# Method to attach local images to actions seems missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Since using the standard SharePhoto doesn't allow you to add your own description, captions and other stuff. I am using OpenGraphStories share dialog. Now the problem is the facebook documentation says :

[image]

BUT!!! I cant find the `addPhoto()` anywhere. I have searched their references and even the pre 4.0 docs.

Code snippet:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject place = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putString("og:type", "place")
    .putString("og:title", "sample title")
    .putString("og:description", "sample description")
    .putString("place:location:latitude", "Sample Location: Latitude")
    .putString("place:location:longitude", "Sample Location: Longitude")
    .build();

ShareOpenGraphAction publish = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType("news.publishes")
    .putObject("place", place)
    .build();

SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(mCombinedBitmap)
    .setUserGenerated(true)
    .build();

ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("news")
    .setAction(publish)
    .build();

mShareDialog.show(ShareActivity.this, content);
```

-EDIT-

i found this `putPhoto(String key, SharePhoto photo)` which you can use in a `ShareOpenGraphObject` although I don't know the key yet. There is only the `"og:image"` but it's type only accepts URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the key `"og:image"` can accept SharePhoto objects.

So you can do:

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
    .setBitmap(bitmap)
    .build();

ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putPhoto("og:image", photo)
    .build();
```

Comment: +1, however this fails if you fall back on the web dialog - if your FB app is not present on the device.

Comment: @User3 yes you can't share local images through the web dialog even when using basic sharing

Comment: Is this a bug? I will report if this is!

Comment: no, you can only use image urls. If you really want to use your local image through a web dialog, you must upload it first

Comment: So to say I need to supply a link to `.putPhoto("ogimage", bitmap)` How will a link work in this scenario?

Comment: `.putPhoto("og:image", URL)`.  
the web dialog downloads whatever image is in the source url

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the image to the Action as said in documentation. The key is "image" see how it's used in a sample: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java#L361-L362